# How Can I Use Tensorflow's `compute_output_shape function' to trace the sizes of feature maps in deep nets

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to measure the size of my feature maps at each layer of a deep net.
I'm doing this because I want to understand the differences between two nets
that I thought had equivalent architectures, though expressed differently - one used the Sequential method, the other used the Functional API (see [SourceQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74697284/do-architectures-built-using-tf-keras-models-sequential-run-more-slowly-and-accu?noredirect=1#comment131891053_74697284), if interested).

The model I'm having difficulty characterizing uses the Functional API input. I can't just use the `get_shape` function, because I didn't specify the Input Shape, so I'm trying to use the `compute_output_shapes` function instead.

The Functional API model was constructed like using one class to construct VGG-ish blocks and another class to construct the net as follows:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model

class Mini_Block2(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, pool_size=2, strides=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.filters = filters
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
            
        # Define a Conv2D layer, specifying filters, kernel_size, activation and padding.
        self.conv2D_0 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=filters, 
                                                        kernel_size=kernel_size, 
                                                        activation='relu',
                                                        strides=strides,
                                                        padding='valid')
        
        # Define the max pool layer that will be added after the Conv2D blocks
        self.max_pool = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size, 
                                                     strides=strides,
                                                     padding='valid')
  
    def call(self, inputs):
        # access the class's conv2D_0 layer
        conv2D_0 = self.conv2D_0
        
        # Connect the conv2D_0 layer to inputs
        x = conv2D_0(inputs)

        # Finally, add the max_pool layer
        max_pool = self.max_pool(x)
        
        return max_pool
    
class MiniVGG2(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super().__init__()

        # Creating blocks of VGG with the following 
        # (filters, kernel_size, repetitions) configurations
        self.block_a = Mini_Block2(filters=32, kernel_size=3)
        self.block_b = Mini_Block2(filters=64, kernel_size=3)
        self.block_c = Mini_Block2(filters=128, kernel_size=3)
        self.block_d = Mini_Block2(filters=128, kernel_size=3)        

        # Classification head
        # Define a Flatten layer
        self.flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
        # Create a Dense layer with 512 units and ReLU as the activation function
        self.fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')
        # Finally add the softmax classifier using a Dense layer
        self.classifier = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    def call(self, inputs):
        # Chain all the layers one after the other
        x = self.block_a(inputs)
        x = self.block_b(x)
        x = self.block_c(x)
        x = self.block_d(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.fc(x)
        x = self.classifier(x)
        return x

vgg2 = MiniVGG2(num_classes=1)

# Compile with losses and metrics
vgg2.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(learning_rate = 1e-4), 
              loss='binary_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])
hist = vgg2.fit(dataset, validation_data=d2, epochs=10)
```

Tragically, this net tends to run out of memory when I try to train it, unlike a net created using Sequential, which I believe to be identical to this one (see [SourceQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74697284/do-architectures-built-using-tf-keras-models-sequential-run-more-slowly-and-accu?noredirect=1#comment131891053_74697284), if interested).

So, I decided to look at how the sizes of each layer evolved.

I scanned thru my net with this function:

```
def feature_map_info2(model, input_shape):
    for layer in model.layers:
        mp_err_flag = False
        print(layer.name)

        try:
            # Go to the sub-layers of a Block layer
            print("      Sub-layers:", layer.layers[0].name, ",",layer.layers[1].name)
            output_shape = layer.layers[0].compute_output_shape(input_shape)
            try:
                output_shape = layer.layers[1].compute_output_shape(output_shape.as_list())
            except:
                mp_err_flag = True
        except:
            output_shape = layer.compute_output_shape(input_shape)
        print("     ", output_shape)
        if mp_err_flag:
            print("       Problem computing output shape for",layer.layers[1].name )
        input_shape = output_shape.as_list()
```

When I execute it with **feature_map_info2(vgg2, [224,224,3])**, I get the following output:

```
mini__block2
      Sub-layers: conv2d , max_pooling2d
      (222, 222, 32)
       Problem computing output shape for max_pooling2d
mini__block2_1
      Sub-layers: conv2d_1 , max_pooling2d_1
      (220, 220, 64)
       Problem computing output shape for max_pooling2d_1
mini__block2_2
      Sub-layers: conv2d_2 , max_pooling2d_2
      (218, 218, 128)
       Problem computing output shape for max_pooling2d_2
mini__block2_3
      Sub-layers: conv2d_3 , max_pooling2d_3
      (216, 216, 128)
       Problem computing output shape for max_pooling2d_3
flatten
      (216, 27648)
dense
      (216, 512)
dense_1
      (216, 1)
```

I am puzzled, by these 2 problems:

Firstly - Computing output shapes for max pooling layers only avoids an error if I prepend the shape list with `None`, although the other layers don't require this. Also, although it avoids a computer error, it still gives an incorrect answer, and I have verified that the `pool_size` is (2,2) as seen in the below sample from a Jupyter notebook:

```
zz = vgg2.layers[0].layers[1].compute_output_shape([None,224,224,3])
vgg2.layers[0].layers[1].name,vgg2.layers[0].layers[1].pool_size,zz

('max_pooling2d', (2, 2), TensorShape([None, 223, 223, 3]))
```

Because of the (2,2) pool size, I exoected a TensorShape of [None, 112, 112, 3], not [None,224,224,3]. Also, why did I need to prepend the Shape list with `None`, when "none" of the other layers required this?

Secondly - The flatten function returns a 2D vector with shape (216, 216*128), instead of (216 * 216 * 128)

Does this make sense to anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should call the `feature_map_info2` model with shapes, `[None, 224,224,3]`

```
feature_map_info2(vgg2, (None,224, 224, 3))
```

You have set the stride for the max pooling layer as `1`. Set it to 2,

Change your code to-

```
class Mini_Block2(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, pool_size=2, strides=1, max_pool_stride=2):
        super().__init__()
        self.filters = filters
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
            
        # Define a Conv2D layer, specifying filters, kernel_size, activation and padding.
        self.conv2D_0 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=filters, 
                                                        kernel_size=kernel_size, 
                                                        activation='relu',
                                                        strides=strides,
                                                        padding='same')
        
        # Define the max pool layer that will be added after the Conv2D blocks
        self.max_pool = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size, 
                                                     strides=max_pool_stride,
                                                     padding='same')
```

Calling `feature_map_info2(vgg2, (None,224, 224, 3))`, you should get,

```
mini__block2_4
      Sub-layers: conv2d_15 , max_pooling2d_12
      (None, 112, 112, 32)
mini__block2_5
      Sub-layers: conv2d_16 , max_pooling2d_13
      (None, 56, 56, 64)
mini__block2_6
      Sub-layers: conv2d_17 , max_pooling2d_14
      (None, 28, 28, 128)
mini__block2_7
      Sub-layers: conv2d_18 , max_pooling2d_15
      (None, 14, 14, 128)
flatten_3
      (None, 25088)
dense_3
      (None, 512)
dense_4
      (None, 1)
```

Comment: Thx for taking the time (again) to respond, but I think your answer doesn't apply for a few reasons. (1) Even with the None, the MaxPool Layer still gives the wrong output, since the pool size is (2,2).(2) Changing the stride only effects the Conv layer, not the MaxPool layer.(3) I'm trying to duplicate a net whose Conv layers use a stride of 1, not 2. (4)Prepending 'None' only seems to be req'd for the MaxPooling layer, not any of the others, which is odd.

Comment: You should not change the stride for conv only for max pool. Check the code above

Comment: Either way, with stride=1 and pool size = 2, the pool layer is not giving the correct answer. The net I'm attempting to duplicate uses a stride of 1 and none of the other layers need to have None prepended to the list. I suspect it's because it refers to batch size, which is irrelevant for computing the feature map size.

Comment: post your output, if you are not getting the above.

Comment: The error lies in the different ways conv2D and MaxPool default their strides. For MaxPool, the default of stride is None, but when the stride value is None, it sets stride equal to pool_size. So, the Seq. model I was trying to copy actually had stride=1 for the conv layer and a stride=2 for the pool layer. When I correct for this the 2 models match. Prepending the shape list with None with these corrections has feature_map_info2 give correct output. But I'm still puzzled why some layers needed None to work and others didn't. I also want to understand the max_pool output I first got with None.

Comment: @VM I should've looked at your code more carefully - I see now you were distinguishing between the strides of the conv layer & pool layer.... Thx again, for taking the time to repeatedly respond.