# How to understand shape of weights returned by layer.get_weights() function?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tensor

I was working with manipulating weights of a CNN model (LENET-5) for my academical project where I encountered this problem that it was very difficult to understand what the keras function `layer.get_weights()` return? My model is

```
# Create Model LENET-5 Traditional
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(filters=6, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='tanh', input_shape=(28, 28, 1), padding="same"),
    AveragePooling2D(),  # pool_size=(2, 2),
    Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='tanh', input_shape=(10, 10, 1)),
    AveragePooling2D(),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(units=120, activation='tanh'),
    Dense(units=84, activation='tanh'),
    # Softmax function gives probabilities of each output class
    Dense(units=10, activation='softmax')
])
```

that gives us a summary of:

[image]

Now after compiling and training the model, the `get_weights()` function for a first *conv2d* layer returns a np array of **shape: (5, 5, 1, 6)**

Now we know that in first Conv2d layer of LENET-5, there are 6 kernels of 1 channel (grayscale) all containing 5x5 = 25 parameters right? but the array looks like this:

[image]

it is 1 array that contains 5 arrays that have 5 more arrays with 1 array of 6 elements. how do I map these to 6 kernels ? which 25 values are from 1st kernel ?  it is not understandable because 6 kernels that contains 5x5 weights are present there. Can anyone please elaborate the mapping of these weights to kernels/filters?

To get access of a single weight I need `weight[0][0][0][0][0]` that returns the first element of first array but I don't know how and which kernel it belongs to. and let's suppose if I want to access weight of 3rd kernel that is on 3rd row and 3rd column how can I access that? there must be an interpretation to that.
I expect someone to please explain me about the shape of weight returned by `get_weights()` function and how I can map them to kernels of conv2d layer.. Visualization can help a lot too.

Comment: weights shape `(5, 5, 1, 6)` represents `(kernel_size_x, kernel_size_y, channels/width, no. of filters)`. If you want to access the third filter you do `weight[:, :, :, 2]`

Comment: Thankyou for responding, Sir, I understand what shape (5,5,1,6) means, but the numpy array that get_weights() function is returning is not understandable, if you read the last few passages, you'll get better awareness on my question.

Comment: `for layer in model.layers: print(layer.name, [ w for w in layer.weights])` . You can print the layer name and the weights associated with it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, but unfortunately, it still does not give me kernel wise weights. Which 5x5 weights exactly belong to kernel 1? or kernel 2?

Comment: Are you saying you are not getting similar results as mentioned here with the loop? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74748303/how-can-i-use-tensorflows-compute-output-shape-function-to-trace-the-sizes-of/74750724?noredirect=1#comment131940276_74750724